# Invalid vector iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, std, stdvector

`std::vector` iterators can be implemented as pointers. A corollary is that if you add elements to the vector, outstanding iterators will obviously become invalid because in general the vector data will have to be reallocated.

A first guess regarding the exact rules would be that the allowed operations are exactly the same as those for pointers e.g. don't dereference an invalid iterator until it has been reassigned a valid value, but that doesn't seem to be quite true because Microsoft's implementation in debug mode will sometimes throw an exception if you e.g. subtract vector iterators pointing to different data blocks (which is helpful for debugging, to be sure).

Is the addendum to the pointer rules something like 'don't subtract iterators to different data blocks' or 'don't do any arithmetic on an invalid iterator until it has been reassigned a valid value' or something else?

For example, is the following program (which seems to work on both Microsoft C++ and GCC) valid?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::vector;

template<class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, vector<T>& v) {
    os << '[';
    bool c = 0;
    for (auto a: v) {
        if (c)
            os << ", ";
        c = 1;
        os << a;
    }
    return os << ']';
}

void f(vector<int>& v, vector<int>::iterator& i) {
    *i = 10;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        v.insert(begin(v), j);
    i = begin(v)+5;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        v.push_back(i);
    auto i = begin(v)+5;
    f(v, i);
    i[1] = 11;
    cout << v << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "iterators pointing to different data blocks"?

Comment: And why would the example program not be valid? At which point does anything happen that you think isn't valid?

Comment: @jogojapan different vectors, or elements of the same vector before and after adding new elements has caused a reallocation.

Comment: He inserts multiple elements, if he inserts enough elements then you will need to reallocate the vector (possible into a different memory location) and then 'i' can become invalid

Comment: @jogojapan I think it is valid; it invalidates an iterator but doesn't do anything with it except reassign it a valid value. I'm just trying to figure out where exactly is the boundary that I'm hopefully on the right side of.

Comment: @rwallace Ok. Subtracting (and then dereferencing) iterators from different vectors is invalid (but that is the same as for pointers). And subtracting (and then dereferencing) iterators from before and after a re-allocation is invalid two (same as when you re-allocate an conventional array).

Comment: @TomerArazy But `i` is reset after the insertion, using `begin(v)`. That's perfectly valid.

Comment: @jogojapan right, but with pointers the mere act of subtraction is okay if you don't then dereference, isn't it? Or does the C++ standard now regard that as strictly speaking undefined behavior even for pointers?

Comment: @jogojapan - You're right, I missed that

Comment: The exact rules of iterator invalidation are spelled out in the standard and need not be guessed. According to these rules, your program's behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @rwallace Hmmm. Ok. Strictly speaking, indeed, the operation of subtracting from a random-access iterator an amount greater than its distance from the beginning is not defined. That is, the operation itself is not defined. Perhaps there is a difference here to pointers. (I also have a feeling that we are splitting hairs here... for all intents and purposes, iterators are meant to act in the same way as (or, as an abstraction of) pointers, §24.2.1).

Comment: *with pointers the mere act of subtraction is okay if you don't then dereference* ― no it's not. Any pointer arithmetic operation is UB if either operand or the result are invalid.

Comment: @n.m. Interesting. I wasn't sure about this wrt pointers. But regarding your previous comment: What part of the program is UB?

Comment: My mistake, it's probably not undefined, it just has too many variables named `i`.

Answer (score -1):

Your example is not valid, the reason why it works is luck. Every operation that can possibly cause a reallocation in a vector may invalidate all iterators.

Comment: Could you explain what part of the code you refer to specifically? Also note that merely invalidating an iterator doesn't mean the program is invalid. It just means there are certain things you must not do with that iterator.